# Windows 10 taskbar icons don't stop glowing orange

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, icons

I've been running into this UI issue on Windows 10 where when I get a notification through an app (especially Slack or Outlook), the icon glows orange to indicate it, but it never goes back to normal. The icon just stays orange unless I kill the app and relaunch it.

Is this a setting for some reason or a bug?

```
Windows 10 Pro
Version 1607
OS Build 14393.51
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution to this problem, so for anyone who comes across this:

My solution was to change the blink rate of the keyboard caret in my Windows settings to something greater than zero.

```
Control Panel > Keyboard > Cursor blink rate: set to something greater than "None"
```

Comment: @NicolasMartel Yep, I was trying to go for a block-style caret that didn't blink, apparently that property of the caret is tied to the notification animations some how? Bizarre

Comment: Incredible... I have been looking for a solution to this for the past week. Unreal.

Comment: Still happens in Windows 10 20H2. Never seen a weirder bug.

Comment: Worked a charm on my Windows 10 machine. Had to reboot though before it took effect.

Comment: Can it be that the flashing speed is bound to this rate? And that in case of "None", it unintentionally gets stuck forever? I've certainly seen stupid stuff....

Comment: damn, this is the worst "feature" I've ever seen on Windows 10. I intentionally have the cursor to "None" because I dislike cursor blinking in general. So it's a tradeoff huh. Definitely the microsoft team should deal with the issue. it's a 100% bug.